# WAMP Orange Icon

Tags: apache, wamp

I installed the wamp server(3.1.0 64bit) yesterday and the icon stoped on orange color and get "httpd.exe error (0x000007b)"
I did many things but the problem not solved. what i did untill now:

1-change te port from 80 to 8080 or even 81.

2-change skype setting in order to not use port 80

3-un-checked IIS from Windows Features

4-uninstalling Some Of my applications Like Torrent and etc.

### this is the 80's port test text by wamp:

***** Test which uses port 80 *****

===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====

Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol

Test for TCPv6

Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol

===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====

Your port 80 is not actually used.

---

this wamp using Apache 2.4.27 version
Im using win7 x64 and don't know what else to do and cant choose to reInstall my windows so help me with this Please.tnx

Answer (score 1):

> ***** Test which uses port 80 *****
>
> ===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====
>
> Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol
>
> Test for TCPv6
>
> Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol
>
> ===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====
>
> Your port 80 is not actually used.

**If port is not used and you haven't misconfigured anything** in the conf files it is most likely that you haven't installed Visual C++ Redistribuable Packages. (Also **error code** references to that issue).

Please check following link [here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

and download and install all required Redistributable Packages both x32 and x64.